# Subsequent cout statements changing text in my initial cout

Tags: c++, file-handling, cout

When I run the below code my expectation is to print to screen the text which says "file characters are", followed by the chars in the file separated by | character.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream in;
    string filename = "binFile.txt";
    int size = std::filesystem::file_size(filename);
    in.open(filename, ios::in | ios::binary);

    cout << "file characters are" << flush;
    // cout << "file characters are" << endl; this works as expected

    char ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        in.read(&ch, sizeof(char));
        cout << ch << "|";
    }   
}
```

However, for some reason the string "file characters are" is not getting displayed correctly instead the '**f**' in "file characters are" is getting replaced by '**|**', i.e.

```
|ile characters are1|2|....
...Remaining text.....
```

I tried  using flush in my `cout` command but it still does not work, however using `endl` at the end of `cout` works. Could anyone let me know why the `cout` is having this weird behaviour?

Comment: You're probably reading and outputting carriage return '\r' characters -- hence the weird output.

Comment: Yes I could verify I am reading \r characters, by comparing with if condition. What is the right way to read and display a file with \r chars,

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`std::isprint`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint) and base your output logic on the value it returns for each character.

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine for me:

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

```
cat file_characters.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    ifstream in;
    string filename = string(argv[1]);
    int size=fs::file_size(filename);  
    in.open(filename, ios::in | ios::binary);
    cout << "file characters are"<<flush;
    //cout << "file characters are"<<endl; this works as expected
    char ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        in.read(&ch, sizeof(char));
        cout << ch << "|";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
g++ -std=c++17 file_characters.cpp
```

```
 a.out a.out | tr '\014' '\012' | head -1
file characters are|E|L|F|||||||||||||||>||||||�|$|||||||@||||||||X|y|||||||||||||@|| ||||||||||||@||||||||@||||||||@||||||||�||||||||�|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||�||||||||�||||||||||||||||||||||||| |||||||| |||||||| |||||||U||||||||U|||||||||||||||||||||||||@||||||||@||||||||@|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||`|L|||||||`|\|||||||`|\|||||||�||||||||�||||||||||||||||||||||||x|L|||||||x|\|||||||x|\||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||8||||||||8||||||||8|||||||| |||||||| ||||||||||||||||||||||X||||||||X||||||||X||||||||D||||||||D||||||||||||||||S|�|t|d|||||8||||||||8||||||||8|||||||| |||||||| |||||||||||||||P|�|t|d|||||T|@|||||||T|@|||||||T|@|||||||d||||||||d||||||||||||||||Q|�|t|d|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||R|�|t|d|||||`|L|||||||`|\|||||||`|\|||||||�||||||||�||||||||||||||||/|l|i|b|6|4|/|l|d|-|l|i|n|u|x|-|x|8|6|-|6|4|.|s|o|.|2||||||||||||||||||G|N|U|||||�|||||||||||||||||||||||||G|N|U||�|h|�|�||�|�|8||�|�|�|�|�||>|t|#|| |||||||||||||G|N|U||||||||||||||||||||||||||-||||||||||||||�|||| ||-||||||||.||||�|e|�|m|4|�|=|�||�|
```